# implicit declaration for database session playframework

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a project with scala playframework and I implicitly declared the database connection session so that I can read/write to mysql database without having to call the database session every time. Is this a good practice?

Is there any trade off?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "any thread off"?

Comment: Do you mean "trade off"? An understandable mistake given how obsessed we all are with concurrent programming during the holiday season.

Comment: @vidya sorry trade off. i have edited it. thanks

Comment: No worries. I figured that's what you meant. I was just kidding.

Answer (score 1):

Working with implicit sessions is certainly preferable so the framework can manage those details for you. The only real downside is needing `(implicit s: Session)` on all your methods, but this can be [worked around](https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/issues/20).

There is also the added benefit of making things more "pluggable" during testing.

Answer (score 0):

Passing "contextual" information around via implicits is a reasonable practice.  You can even see this with the `ExecutionContext` passed to futures in the Scala standard library.

It's definitely better than global values or pseudo-global values in a singleton object, and it makes things easier to mock when testing.